# why back button display with slide menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

[image]I am trying to make a simple application of Ionic  framwork using this command 
 **ionic start app  sidemenu** .I don't want to display slide menu on first screen .So I have one screen in which there is one button .On click of that button I move to second state from This state I need slide menu option .But along the slide menu I am able to

http://plnkr.co/edit/VTrB2hWTGMlUPzRTuvDg?p=preview

```
.controller('testcntr', function($scope, $stateParams,$state) {
  $scope.moveTo=function(){
    $state.go('app.playlists')
  }
})[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: are you sure you completed your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why the back button button not display in second screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730836/why-the-back-button-button-not-display-in-second-screen)

Answer (score 0):

In Your case 
remove `<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i>Back</ion-nav-back-button>` from **menu.html**

keep it simple in nav bar like bellow.

```
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
 </ion-nav-bar>
```