# why the back button button not display in second screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

why the back button is not display while moving one page to another page ?As in  how user move to move navigate to previous page ? I  disable on on second  page but it is not display on any page

```
 $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      disableBack: true
    });
    $state.go('app.playlists');
```

Actually I have one button on that click I move to another page which have slide menu .On click of any option in slide menu user not able to move to previous page

Please click the button button and move to slide menu screen and select and option from slide it move to second screen but there is no back button so user not able to move previous screen

http://plnkr.co/edit/17MJo0Ma81Zf4lBl8vuG?p=preview

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$ionicHistory) {


}).controller('a', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $ionicHistory) {

  $scope.moveto = function() {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      disableBack: true
    });
    $state.go('app.playlists');

  }

})
```

Comment: Any feedback for my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you're using an old css reference ?

This is your plunker:

```
<link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" />
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

and this is what it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" />
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

this is the forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0ykI5fU1k5a6qqlrdoa?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Simply , you forget to add a  "**ion-nav-bar**" to your "**playlist.html**"

```
<ion-view title="Playlist">

  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
      <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>


  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <h1>Playlist</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXETYnlwzlY8g1qKETSz?p=preview)